# How to pass latitude and logitude from database to ejs file in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps, ejs

I have latitude and longitude in database. How to pass those value to my show page.

This is my ejs file

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<img src="<%= destination.image %>">
<h4><%= destination.name %></h4>     
<p><%= destination.description %></p>
    
    
<script>
function initMap() {
    var uluru = {lat: -25.344, lng: 131.036};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(
        document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 4, center: uluru});
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: uluru, map: map});
}
</script>
```

Comment: What database are you using? You'll probably need to use "fetch" to get those values from your database. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: I use mongodb, mongoose

Comment: Your <%= destination.name %> has nothing to do with lat and lng? Just save them as variables or in a hidden text field and use them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code solved my problem

```js
<script>
function initMap() {
    // The location of object
    var object = {lat: <%= destination.lat %>, lng: <%= destination.lang %>};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(
        document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 13, center: object});
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: object, map: map});
}
</script>
```

But vs code detect as errors in every ejs tag